# Extract the strings that follows a regex pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

The list of original inputs are a list of free text field. The task is to extract a pattern like `"234-5678"` from the string.

For example the list in the following:

```
text <- c("abced 156-8790","kien 3578-562839 bewsd","$nietl 66320-98703","789-55340")
```

what I would like to extract is:

```
return <- c("156-8790","578-5628","320-9870","789-5534")
```

I was considering to use `gsub("^[([:digit:]{3})[-]([:digit:]{4})]", replacement = "", text)`, but the regex does not work the way I wanted. Could anyone please help with this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you really want to use `gsub`, something like this will work `gsub(".*(\\d{3}-\\d{4}).*","\\1",text)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to match 3 digits (`\\d{3}`) followed by a `-` , followed 4 digits (`\\d{4}`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(text, "\\d{3}-\\d{4}")
#[1] "156-8790" "578-5628" "320-9870" "789-5534"
```

---

Or using `base R` with `regmatches/regexpr`

```
regmatches(text, regexpr("\\d{3}-\\d{4}", text))
#[1] "156-8790" "578-5628" "320-9870" "789-5534"
```